# Unable to use Dynamodb locally with Node 18.13.0

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I have a problem that I do not understand. With node 18.13.0, I am not able to use Dynamodb locally.

I always get this error:
"message": "UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: localhost' at port 8005'. This service may not be available in the `localhost' region.",
"type": 0

But with node 16 I have no problem.
Here is all the information I can give you, I am on mac (m1) on Ventura 13.1 (also on windows 11).

The serveless version:

- Framework Core: 3.27.0 (local) 3.27.0 (global)
- Plugin: 6.2.3
- SDK: 4.3.2

Here is my serverless.yml:

```
service: hydradis-planning-delivery
provider:
  name: aws
functions:
  - '${file(routes.yml)}'
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
custom:
  dynamodb:
    start:
      port: 8005
  serverless-offline:
    httpPort: 3005
    lambdaPort: 3015
```

Here is my connection:

```
var dynamoDbCreation = new AWS.DynamoDB({
region: 'localhost',
endpoint: ('http://localhost:8005')
});
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you start DynamoDB Local? Does netstat, or equivalent, show it listening on port 8005?

Comment: Yes DynamoDB run in local

Comment: AWS Lambda node.18x runtime does not use the AWS SDK 2.0 by default. So the DynamoDB code probably wron there. You have 2 option, install the 2.0 aws sdk. Or rewrite the code to support 3.0. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html

Comment: I don't know why, but yesterday there was a response that gave the answer. If I replace the localhost in the region field with 127.0.0.1 it works. Thanks anyway for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use literal string `localhost` as region but rather the endpoint:

```
var dynamoDbCreation = new AWS.DynamoDB({
region: 'http://127.0.0.1:8005',
endpoint: ('http://localhost:8005')
});
```